# Is it possible to use the left join and annotate function in django?

Tags: django, orm

```
# model
class User(AbstractUser):
     pass
class Post(models.Model):
     post = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True)


# sql
SELECT A.username
      ,COUNT(B.*)
FROM users_user A
LEFT JOIN post B
  ON B.user_id = A.id
GROUP BY A.id
```

users_user model is default django user model

I want to change query to orm

I tried both "post" and "post_set" using select_related, but I couldn't.

Comment: Share your models.

Comment: I just added a model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

User.objects.annotate(num_posts=Count('post'))
```

The `User` objects that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.num_posts`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).